# How do I access the db shell for SQLite on a Django project?

Tags: django, sqlite

I am trying to update the column on a variable to allow null in a db shell so that I don't have to drop my table.

I have notice **data.sqlite** lives on the main folder and **sqlite3.db** lives on the "main app" subfolder. Why is that? Which one is the one I want to access?

I know they are 2 different files and in 2 different directories and that this is the standard configuration when a Django project is generated. I guess my question is what is the difference between this two files and if there is a reason they are not in the same folder. Thank!

Answer (score 18):

As with all database backends:

```
./manage.py dbshell
```

Comment: Thanks. What about the reason data.sqlite is in one place and sqlite3.db is in another place? Is one the schema?

Comment: No, sqlite doesn't use a separate schema. The db goes in the path/file you specify in settings.DATABASES - perhaps you changed it at some point?

Comment: I am pretty sure they are 2 different files and in 2 different directories and this is the standard configuration when a Django project is generated. I guess my question is what is the difference between this two files and if there is a reason they are not in the same folder. Thank!

Comment: Worth pointing out - for `dbshell` to work, the client binary for the database needs to be available in your system (and in your `PATH`). For sqlite, the client is called `sqlite3`. Just having Python installed is not sufficient.