# CommandError: You appear not to have the 'sqlite3' program installed or on your path

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I recently installed Django to use as a web framework and I am trying use the command `python manage.py dbshell` to access the database shell for SQLite as said in this post: [How do I access the db shell for SQLite on a Django project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757897/how-do-i-access-the-db-shell-for-sqlite-on-a-django-project). It gives me the error `CommandError: You appear not to have the 'sqlite3' program installed or on your path.`

I downloaded the sqlite.exe file and saved it in the directory `C:\sqlite\sqlite3.exe`. I then added that directory to my path in the command prompt, but it still gives the same error. Am I not adding it to my path correctly? I am using Windows 10 64 bit, but with python 32 bit installed.

I downloaded the file from https://www.sqlite.org/download.html, and I downloaded the file `sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3120200.zip`

Comment: I ran into this issue while using Visual Studio Code. I kept performing the Reload Window command and the terminal inside VSC kept throwing an error after trying to run the dbshell command. I exited out of VSC and reopened it. This fixed the problem. As I have read in other places, the reload window action does not necessarily do what you would assume it might.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After you add the directory to your `PATH`, close and reopen Command Prompt. This will make the changes to `PATH` available to your current Command Prompt session.

Comment: Do I add it to my system or user path

Answer (score 38):

If you run it in the linux, pls install sqlite3 cli firstly

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
```

Comment: This worked for me in Ubuntu. Was looking for various solutions but ultimately this worked

Comment: This worked for me in MX Linux.

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same problem. Finally, I found a decision:

- downloaded sqlite3.exe from https://www.sqlite.org/2015/sqlite-shell-win32-x86-3081002.zip and saved it to the another directory
- added that directory to the environment variable PATH
- closed and reopened CMD windows terminal
- and just after that command `sqlite3` worked for me and I saw a message `SQLite version 3.8.10.2 2015-05-20 18:17:19 ...`.

Answer (score 4):

**If you are on linux ditribution:**

1. Frist **install sqlite3** with this command `sudo apt-get install sqlite` via terminal.
2. After that, use this one command to access sql shell  `python manage.py dbshell`.

Comment: sqlite does not exist. Its called sqlite3 now.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with visual studio code, I re-launched the application and it worked fine .

Answer (score -1):

One solution that works for me is that I saved the downloaded files to the folder where the file manage.py is located.